# c# to vb conversion issues - Is this line correct?

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

I am trying to convert this line to vb.net:

```cs
using var scorer = new YoloScorer<YoloCocoP5Model>("Assets/Weights/yolov5s.onnx");
```

I converted it like this (renaming also scorer to my scorer, and correcting the path):

```vb
Dim myscorer As New Yolov5Net.Scorer.YoloScorer(Of Yolov5Net.Scorer.Models.YoloCocoP5Model)("Assets/Weights/best.onnx")
```

Visual studio is not complaining, so I assume that the conversion is correct, but unfortunately its also not returning anything later in the code, so its not working properly. This line is the only one I am still not sure at the moment. What is the anotation `<xxx>(...)`?

Comment: You didn't translate the `using`: this is new C# syntax for a "using" block. That object gets disposed at the end of the scope

Comment: The correct conversion would be: `Using scorer As New YoloScorer(Of YoloCocoP5Model)("Assets/Weights/yolov5s.onnx") CODEHERE End Using` If you don't use the `Using`, please make sure to call `myscorer.Dispose` when done using that object.

Comment: Other than the `using`, this is pretty much the same. The `<...>` is called "generics"

Comment: As far as I know, you translated `<xxx>` correctly to `(Of xxx) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to import `Yolov5Net.Scorer` and `Yolov5Net.Scorer.Models` since C# is doing the same indicated by the lack of fully qualified namespaces.

My second suggestion would be to use a Using declaration like what C# is doing:

```vb
Using myscorer As New YoloScorer(Of YoloCocoP5Model)("Assets/Weights/best.onnx")
    ' do something with myscorer
End Using
```